# Parsing the parsed column inside awk

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, unix, awk

I am trying to use awk for parsing a text file that looks like this:

```
001  data   John    Smith   address "London" | occupation "Driver" | exercise_level "Medium"
002  data   Rob Edward  address "Cardiff" | occupation "Physiotherapist" | exercise_level "High"
003  data   Dara    Pronk   address "Groningen" | country "Holland" | occupation "Teacher" | exercise_level "Low"
004  data   Marina  Francesca   address "Lugano" | country "Switzerland" | occupation "Chef" | exercise_level "High"
```

The first 4 columns are separated by tab and the 5th column has some metadata separated by pipes.

I want to get the "values" of the occupation "key" as my fifth column. My desired output will look like this:

```
001  data   John    Smith   Driver
002  data   Rob Edward  Physiotherapist
003  data   Dara    Pronk   Teacher
004  data   Marina  Francesca   Chef
```

I am able to get the occupation by this command:

```
awk -F'[\t|]' '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^ occupation/){c=$i}} print $1, $2, $3, $4, c}' my_file
```

However, it will have both the key and value together (e.g. occupation "Physiotherapist" instead of just Physiotherapist). Is there a way to kind of parse the parsed column (i.e. parsing the value inside quotes), something like below?

```
awk -F'[\t|]' '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^ occupation/){c=$i}} ((parse c here, take $2 of " delimiter)) print $1, $2, $3, $4, c}' my_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk

```
$ awk '{match($0,/occupation "([^"]*)"/,arr);print $1,$2,$3,$4,arr[1]}' infile
001 data John Smith Driver
002 data Rob Edward Physiotherapist
003 data Dara Pronk Teacher
004 data Marina Francesca Chef
```

Other awk

```
$ awk '{
         match($0,/occupation "([^"]*)"/); 
         s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); 
         gsub(/.* "|"/,"",s); 
         print $1,$2,$3,$4,s
}' infile
001 data John Smith Driver
002 data Rob Edward Physiotherapist
003 data Dara Pronk Teacher
004 data Marina Francesca Chef
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
001  data   John    Smith   address "London" | occupation "Driver" | exercise_level "Medium"
002  data   Rob Edward  address "Cardiff" | occupation "Physiotherapist" | exercise_level "High"
003  data   Dara    Pronk   address "Groningen" | country "Holland" | occupation "Teacher" | exercise_level "Low"
004  data   Marina  Francesca   address "Lugano" | country "Switzerland" | occupation "Chef" | exercise_level "High"
```

--edit to address comment--

> Just wondering, in the second option (other awk), is it possible to
>   store other variables (e.g. occupation for var s and exercise_level
>   for var e)?

modify variable `search="...."` according to your need, the order you input the same way it will give you result

```
awk -v search="occupation,exercise_level,address" '
BEGIN{
    split(search, arr, /,/) 
}
{
    str = "";
    for(i=1; i in arr; i++)
    {
          regexp = arr[i]" \"([^\"]*)\"";
          if(match($0,regexp)){ 
            s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); 
            gsub(/.* "|"/,"",s);
            str = (str ? str OFS : "") s 
           }
     }
         print $1,$2,$3,$4,str
}' infile
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks a lot!! Just wondering, in the second option (other awk), is it possible to store other variables (e.g. occupation for var s and exercise_level for var e)?

Comment: @kaka01 second option you have to do one by one, copy and paste, change `occupation` to some other key and variable `s` to something else, and same you replace in gsub, or else you can loop it

Comment: Hi @3161993. Thanks! Can you please explain briefly what `str = (str ? str OFS : "") s` means here?

Comment: `str = (str ? str OFS : "") s` is concatenation of variable `str`, suppose you got 2 or more keys to print, then first iteration of loop `str` will be null, so `str = s`, second iteration `str` is not null so `str = str OFS s` and so on, above one can be written as `if(str){ str = str OFS s } else { str = s }`

Answer (score 0):

Using any old awk (GNU works too but is not required):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{split($5,a,/ *\| */); for (i in a) { split(a[i],b," "); d[b[1]]=b[2] } print $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS d["occupation"]}' i
001 data John Smith "Driver"
002 data Rob Edward "Physiotherapist"
003 data Dara Pronk "Teacher"
004 data Marina Francesca "Chef"
```

Split out for easier reading (and commenting):

```
BEGIN {
  OFS=FS='\t'           # set the input field separator
} 

{
  split($5,a,/ *\| */)  # split your embedded array by vertical bar
  for (i in a) {        # step through the array,
    split(a[i],b," ")   # splitting as you go
    #gsub(/"/,"",b[2])  # optionally remove quotes
    d[b[1]]=b[2]        # and assigning indices in a new data array
  }
  print $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS d["occupation"]     # and print the result
}
```

While the extra step of `split()` and the `for` loop may look cumbersome, it has the advantage of making ALL your embedded data available *by name* in a handy array. (This addresses the request you made in comments on 3161993's answer.)

Note that at present, the `split()` breaks on whitespace, so if you want to be able to handle data containing spaces (i.e. inside the quotes), a little more work will be required. If you want the output to be presented without quotes, you can `gsub()` the data after assigning it, within the for loop (to remove all quotes) or use a pair of `sub()` commands to remove leading and trailing quotes.